# How accurately has general relativity's prediction of gravitational redshift been measured?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-redshift

According to Einstein's general relativity, massive bodies should cause gravitational redshift.

How accurately has this been measured?

Comment: What research have you done? Without research, why are you Asking that here, instead of doing some research then coming here with detailed Questions about which parts of your results were unsatisfactory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A recent test (2018) using atomic clocks aboard two satellites found general relativity's gravitational redshift prediction to be accurate to $(+0.19 \pm 2.48)\times10^{-5}$.

This was not a planned experiment and the satellites had accidentally been delivered on elliptic rather than circular orbits in 2014.  They were useless for their original purpose of navigation.  Instead of taking a complete loss, the satellites were repurposed for experimentation.

Previously the most accurate measurement was taken in 1976 by [Gravity Probe A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Probe_A) which had an accuracy of 70 parts per million.  The new test improves the accuracy by a factor of 5.6.

See the paper, "[A gravitational redshift test using eccentric Galileo satellites](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.03711)".

Comment: Could you explain what the units of measurement are for that value?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs:  that is undoubtably a fractional error, so the measured and predicted values agree within $2$ parts in a million.

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks but I didn't mean the scale, but the actual units. eg, meters...

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs:  Fractional errors have no units.  The article is saying that the observed gravitational redshift is as predicted to within this error.

Comment: @RossMillikan maybe I am the one misunderstanding. The value given could be a an error expressed as a proportion of something. But the units of the 'something' are still unclear.

Comment: GR predicts a gravitational redshift of $\frac {\Delta U}{c^2}$ where $\Delta U$ is the difference in gravitational potential.  They measure the redshift and find it is within 2 parts per million of this value.  They divide the observed by the theoretical, so the units cancel.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs It’s like a percentage. Like “I’m 99 per cent sure” means “I’m 1 % uncertain,” meaning your uncertainty is $1\:\%=10^{-2}$ . . . except this is on the order of $10^{-5}$.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish, makes sense. So what are the units of redshift itself?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs It has several different formulae, as the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift) reflects, all of which have unit $1$ because the units in the numerator and denominator cancel. It’s like the coefficient of static friction; it’s just a number.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs Each galileo satellite has 4 clocks (2 Rubidium 2 passive hydrogen masers), so effectively it seems like this study was ultimately measuring the redshift in the 21 cm hydrogen line (1.42 GHz). Of course redshift itself is still unitless

Answer (score 2):

Fifty years, ago, the [Pound-Rebka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment) experiment demonstrated gravitational blue shift on Earth in a tower at Harvard, to an accuracy of 10%.